# Apk file not getting generated

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I have been fooling around with the ndk for android and setup a project follow the instructions in this link http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin and when clean/build or run the project i get an error in the console saying Unable to find ndktest.apk!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following the instructions in that link somehow messed everything up and projects that didnt use the ndk were also not generating R.java and apk files. I fixed this the only way i knew how by re installing everything java/Android related.

Answer (score 0):

if you have imported the project and there are no APK. mostly it will give you this error. 
in this case and what i did last time it was creating new project and copied all the folders from other project to the new one. but u don't simply copy and paste them all. just copy the res folder and src folder to the new project "separately".

Comment: i didnt import the project though i just followed the tutorial in the link and the project wont generate a R.java or .apk

Comment: i guess you'll need to update to the latest ADT plugin. in eclipse click help --> check for updates and if there are no updates then please do it manually by following this. http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html